# App crashing in the part of Grid layout declaration

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Class & XML are not the same

```
public void r(View view)
        {
            LinearLayout linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            activePLayer=0 ;

            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            {
                gameState[i]=2;
            }

            Log.i("Success","0");
//Till this part it's working

            GridLayout gridL = findViewById(R.id.gl);
            Log.i("Success","0");
//This log don't show up

            for(int i=0;i<gridL.getChildCount();i++)
            {
                ((ImageView)gridL.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
            }

        }
```

I want to reset my Connect-3 game made in  a constraint layout to play it again but my app crashes at the point of declaration of GridLayout.
Any suggestions ?

My build error log :-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.vivanksharma.gameconnect, PID: 32090
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
                      at com.vivanksharma.gameconnect.MainActivity.r(MainActivity.java:91)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is written in your stack trace,

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout

your Class & XML are not the same. You need to make sure that the import is correct

to fix this, just switch the current import with:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
```

Comment: Yes there is a method 'r' in OnClick attribute

Comment: i fixed the answer ;)

Comment: yes just change the import in your code to 'android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout'

Comment: What @GalYedidovich is trying to say, change "GridLayout gridL = findViewById(R.id.gl);" line to "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gridL = findViewById(R.id.gl);"

Comment: or you otherwise change the import at the beginning of java file to that. might be cleaner code

Comment: I changed the import in my code to 'import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;' and it worked !

Comment: But I imported that by pressing shortcut keys. Any idea why it imported wrong library ? @GalYedidovich

Comment: that is common, there are more than one class the called GridLayout, you just choose different one that what you have in XML.

Answer (score 3):

Change from

`GridLayout gridLayout  = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);`

to

`androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);`